# The helper "sonata_media" is not defined

Tags: symfony, sonata-media-bundle

I'm using SonataMediaBundle and installed/configured as per instructions in their site
https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/2-2/doc/index.html

I can save a media file and linked to the another entity(ManyToOne) but when I try to render the image path using the following code:

```
<?php echo $view['sonata_media']->thumbnail($media, 'small') ?>
```

It gives me an error :

> The helper "sonata_media" is not defined.

I don't know what I should do. Anyone help me about this ?

Thanks.

Edit: I'm using PHP as templating engine.